# SQL Server 2017 cannot connect to remote databases

Tags: database, sql-server, sql

I tried to uninstall some old versions of SQL Server I had installed just to free up hard drive space, and along the way I corrupted my SQL Server 2017 such that SSMS could no longer connect to any remote databases. After a lot of troubleshooting, I gave up and decided to reinstall SQL Server and SSMS. I uninstalled SQL Server and related software and reinstalled it, but I still have the same problem as before of not being able to connect to remote databases.

- I'm using Windows 10 Home
- I can connect to my local database using SSMS for what it's worth
- I can connect to the remote database from other computers

Here is the "Cannot connect" error:

[image: Here is the "Cannot connect" error]

Here is what I get when I search `SQL` in Add/Remove Programs

[image: Here is what I get when I search <code>SQL</code> in Add/Remove Programs]

How do I get to where I can connect to remote databases again?